# If statement not wirking, python

Tags: python, if-statement

```
 if number == 1:  
    print("One")  
    print("To exit type 'exit'.")

 exit = raw_input()    
    if exit == "exit":       
    print("Welcome back.")
```

I am getting error on the **if exit == "exit":** line...
(Using python 2)
The full error is : 'unindent does not match any outer indentation level'

Comment: And the error is? Probably something about indentation by the looks of it

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or Python 3? The `print` functions look like 3, but the `raw_input` looks like 2.

Comment: @daniel-radosa please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54046828/edit) and include the full text of the error and include which python version you are using.

Comment: When asking about code that produces an Exception you should always include the complete Traceback in the question. Copy the Traceback and paste it in the question, then format it as code (select it and type ctrl-k)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try like this:

```
def raw_input():
    return "exit"
number = 1
if number == 1:  
    print("One")  
    print("To exit type 'exit'.")
exit = raw_input()    
if exit == "exit":       
    print("Welcome back.")
```

Comment: Why do you need to declare `raw_input`here? It will shadow the default `raw_input()` so the next time you want to get the input from the standard input you will always get "exit" because it is now being shadowed

Comment: Just fixing indentation for him. Need to ask the author of the question.

Answer (score 1):

For Python 2.x:

```
if number == 1:  
    print "One" 
    print "To exit type 'exit'."

choice = raw_input()    
    if choice == "exit":       
        print "Welcome back."
```

The `SyntaxError` raised by your code was due to the compound if statement.

It seems you've started a block that is to be indented to inside the if, but it stays at the current indent. Normally, ending an if statement doesn't need an ending indication like `}` but it does freak out when no code *enters* the if statement.

If you wanted it to stay the way it was, add an indented `pass` statement to prevent the error from popping up. It would look like this:

```
...
if choice == "exit":
    pass    # does absolutely nothing, just acknowledges it
...
```

Comment: The error _should_ be `SyntaxError`. If it isn't, it could be either `NameError` if it's in the global namespace or `UnboundLocalError` if it's inside a function / method, though either is pretty unlikely to be the case. It could also be either `IndentationError` or `TabError`, but it would usually raise `SyntaxError`.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't indent the `if exit` statement. You also need to indent your `print("Welcome back.")` statement, like so:

```
if number == 1:
    print("One")  
    print("To exit type 'exit'.")

exit = input()    
if exit == "exit":       
    print("Welcome back.")
```

You'll use `raw_input()` and `print 'xyz'` in Python 2.
Use `input()` and `print('xyz')` in Python 3.